hadoop-azure with DefaultAzureCredential
We develop a spark application and use abfss protocol to consume data from azure storage. Abfss supports various auth methods (like access key, client creds, msi, etc.). However, we would like to use AzureDefaultCredential in python, get a token for storage and use this to authenticate. The benefit would be that we could use the same code for local development and production.
How to achieve this?

As per this documentation to access the adls gen 2 from databricks below are the available option.

OAuth 2.0 with a Microsoft Entra ID service principal
Shared access signatures (SAS)
Account keys

I would recommend you to use OAuth 2.0 with a Microsoft Entra ID service principal.
But you mentioned the benefit that you can use the same code for local development and production using  DefaultAzureCredential.
It works entirely different in local and in production, because the  DefaultAzureCredential follows the credential mentioned in this document until it gets one.
In local it will be different like Azure CLI and in production it will take different like Azure managed identity.
Instead of this you go any of the 3 ways like mentioned above.
If you still wish to use default credentials, follow below steps.
First, give the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to you user assigned managed identity associated with databricks.
Next, using default credential get the SAS token on container of file system level.
Code
account_url = f"https://{accountName}.dfs.core.windows.net"
token_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url, credential=token_credential)

delegation_key_start_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
delegation_key_expiry_time = delegation_key_start_time + timedelta(days=1)

user_delegation_key = service_client.get_user_delegation_key(key_start_time=delegation_key_start_time,key_expiry_time=delegation_key_expiry_time)

start_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
expiry_time = start_time + timedelta(days=1)
sas_permissions=FileSystemSasPermissions(read=True,list=True)

containerLevelSasToken = generate_file_system_sas(accountName, file_system_name=fileSystemName,credential=user_delegation_key,expiry=expiry_time,start=start_time,permission=sas_permissions)

Next, use this token to configure.
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.auth.type.{accountName}.dfs.core.windows.net", "SAS")
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.{accountName}.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.{accountName}.dfs.core.windows.net",containerLevelSasToken)

df = spark.read.csv(f"abfss://data@jadls.dfs.core.windows.net/csv/bulk.csv",header=True)
df.show()

Output:
+-----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------+-------+
|       Date|    Symbol|       Security Name|         Client Name|Buy/Sell|Quantity Traded|Trade Price / Wght. Avg. Price|Remarks|
+-----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------+-------+
|29-JUL-2024| 20MICRONS|  20 Microns Limited|GRAVITON RESEARCH...|     BUY|         370921|                        274.92|      -|
|29-JUL-2024| 20MICRONS|  20 Microns Limited|AAKRAYA RESEARCH LLP|     BUY|         261663|                        281.14|      -|
|29-JUL-2024| 20MICRONS|  20 Microns Limited|   QE SECURITIES LLP|     BUY|         186016|                        279.92|      -|
|29-JUL-2024|     AARON|Aaron Industries ...|SILVER LINE VENTU...|     BUY|          67838|                        310.92|      -|
|29-JUL-2024|       AHL|Abans Holdings Li...|VT CAPITAL MARKET...|     BUY|         213586|                        565.09|      -|
|29-JUL-2024|   ALANKIT|     Alankit Limited|GRAVITON RESEARCH...|     BUY|        1567338|                         27.49|      -|

+-----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------+-------+
only showing top 20 rows


Thanks a lot for your reply. I tried your example with SAS auth. However, I fail because org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider can not be found. What packages should I use? Or did you use your own token provider?

Ok. You need to some configuration. Check this article to add these driver.https://medium.com/@murali.suraparaju/pyspark-adls-gen2-connectivity-using-abfss-859ef9d313c

I know how to configure spark packages. What I don't know is in which package "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider" is. I don't use databricks btw. Just spark in AKS cluster.

Did you referred the article given above?

It consists azure hadoop datalake library which is need.

Also check this module https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/abfs.html

Your medium link uses client creds, not sas. And in the link about hadoop-azure it is explicitly stated that the sas token provider has to be implemented by you. So where did you get your token provider from?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1642365/sas-authentication-does-not-work-with-adsl-gen2-wi check this. You need to add  that hadoop azure datalake jar, also implement the class like given in above solution.
